# Create a yum repository from Artifactory (containing rpm packages)

Tags: centos, artifactory, rpm, yum

I want to create a yum repository from my Artifactory URL where I have various rpm packages available.

I created .repo file as below in /etc/yum.repos.d

```
[customrepo]
name=CustomRepository
baseurl=https://jfrogurl/postgres/13.01.0000
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

After this when I type yum list I get the following error:

> Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'customrepo': repomd.xml parser error: Parse error at line: 32 (Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 0 and head)

Am I missing anything?

Comment: did you create the repository in Artifactory before configuring yum.repos.d?

Comment: already have artifactory repository created

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the `baseurl` in yum.repos.d points to the path which contains the Yum repository [metadata files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/RPM+Repositories#RPMRepositories-RPMMetadataforHostedRPMs).
From your question it looks like you are pointing to `postgres/13.01.0000`. You need to make sure that this path contains the metadata files.
By default the metadata is stored relative to the repository's root folder. In this case, Artifactory searches the entire repository for RPMs and saves the repodata directory at `$REPO-KEY/repodata`. You can control this behavior by [configuring](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/RPM+Repositories#RPMRepositories-LocalRepositories) the *RPM Metadata Folder Depth* parameter.